# api call using userid

Tags: api, vue.js, state, store

I need to make an api call to get recommendations for a user. This is my api url:
http://URL/../../patients/**USER ID**/recommendations

My user Id is saved in my vuex store in the file "patient.module.js:

```
state: {
    id: null,
    email: null,
    password: null,
    location: [],
    specialty: [],
    attribute: [],
    language: [],
    gender: [],
    editUser: false,
  },
  getters: {
    getUserId(state) {
      return state.id;
    },
  },
```

My store structure looks like this:
[image]

In my RecommendationView I try to display the json-response from my api call.
Here I wrote the method to make the api call.

```
     methods: {
    getRecommendations() {
      this.id = this.$store.getters.getUserId;
      return http
        .get(`/patients/${id}/recommendations`)
        .then((response) => {
          this.recommendation = response.data;
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(
            "Ein Fehler beim User ist aufgetreten: " + error.response
          );
        });
    },
  },
```

Unfortunately, I receive this error: id' is not defined
How can I get the patient id from the store and send it with my request?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why is there angular symbols on your files?

Comment: @Erenn I have a visual studio extention called Material Icon Theme and because of the naming it thinks that these are angular-files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `mapState` in computed like this.

```js
<script>
  import {mapState} from "vuex";


export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      user: state => state.patient
    })
  },
  data() {},
  methods: {
    getRecommendations() {
      this.id = this.user.id;
      return http
        .get(`/patients/${id}/recommendations`)
        .then((response) => {
          this.recommendation = response.data;
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(
            "Ein Fehler beim User ist aufgetreten: " + error.response
          );
        });
    },
  }
} 
</script>
```

Comment: I added your code but I get the same error: 
error  'id' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: Ah I think it works to get the user id. Thank you so much!

Comment: Ok, it works to get the user id, but somehow I can't send it to my api. In the function the id is not recognized: error  'id' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: `.get("/patients/${id}/recommendations")` this line need a `this.id` or just `.get("/patients/${this.user.id}/recommendations")`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Now I receive this error:
GET http://URL/.../v1/patients/$%7Bthis.id%7D/recommendations net::ERR_FAILED 500

Comment: Thank you both so much! It works when I use backticks insted of "